# Stuck with a challenge that has me capitalizing the beginning of each word

Tags: javascript

Basically, the challenge is to have an algorithm that takes in a string and that returns the beginning of each word capitalized. Simple enough, but I get stuck at how to capitalize the letter after finding the space in a loop (maybe there's a better way to do it).

Here is my code:

```
 var capitalize = function(string){

var split = string.split(" ");
var collection = [];
var store = [];

for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++){

  if(split[i]){

      if(split[i] === " "){
        var init = split[i+1].toUpperCase();
        store.push(init);
        collection.push(split[i]);
      } else{
        collection.push(split[i]);
      }
  }

}

var temp = collection.join(" ");
var final = temp.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + temp.slice(1);

return final;

}
```

Obviously, inside my for loop, it won't let me make changes to the array that I'm iterating through. Then I tried a while loop, I tried to use array.map and it still doesn't work. I just don't seem to understand how I can capitalize the word after finding the space (" ").

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to add a space here: `string.split("");` - in between the quotes

Comment: `.toUpperCase()` returns the new value and does not change the value in-place

Comment: Andreas, thanks. I'll make the changes. My entire code was centered around upper case making changes to the array itself. Pretty stupid on my part.

Comment: @MabehAl-ZuqYadeek if my answer below solved your problem, please give it a tick ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you split the string by `" "` and make the first letter of each collection entry a uppercase?

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript) how the make the first letter uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to do this in JS when you can do this in CSS

```
p.capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

<p class='capitalize'>
  hello how are you?
</p>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0uu3n29v/)

Comment: Because that's the OP's question, JS code doesn't exactly imply that there is HTML.

Answer (score 0):

No need for all that variables

Just:

`function (str){
     return str.replace(str.charAt(0), str.charAt(0).toUpperCase())
}`

will do.